# LinkedIn Marketing-API: ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT with the bulk create a campaign conversion endpoint

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to use the '[Batch create a campaign conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/conversion-tracking?view=li-lms-2023-07&tabs=https#batch-create-2)' endpoint from the LinkedIn Marketing API.

I'm calling it like this, with the `ids` parameter how it's described in the docs:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/campaignConversions?ids=List((campaign%3Aurn%3Ali%3AsponsoredCampaign%3A<campaignA>%2Cconversion%3Aurn%3Alla%3AllaPartnerConversion%3A<conversionA>)%2C(campaign%3Aurn%3Ali%3AsponsoredCampaign%3A<campaignB>%2Cconversion%3Aurn%3Alla%3AllaPartnerConversion%3A<conversionA>))' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' \
  --header 'LinkedIn-Version: 202307' \
  --header 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0' \
```

I'm using Insomnia to encode the URL query params and I've tried both PUT and POST for this.

I get this error however:

```
{
    "status": 400,
    "code": "ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT",
    "message": "Invalid query parameters passed to request"
}
```

Could anyone help me figure out what's wrong here?

Edit: I was able to get this working by using a newer API version and the following curl request:

```
curl --request PUT \
  --url 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/campaignConversions?ids=List((campaign%3Aurn%3Ali%3AsponsoredCampaign%3A<campaign>%2Cconversion%3Aurn%3Alla%3AllaPartnerConversion%3A<conversion>)%2C(campaign%3Aurn%3Ali%3AsponsoredCampaign%3A<campaign2>%2Cconversion%3Aurn%3Alla%3AllaPartnerConversion%3A<conversion>))' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'LinkedIn-Version: 202401' \
  --header 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0' \
  --data '{"entities":{"(campaign:urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredCampaign%3A<campaign>,conversion:urn%3Alla%3AllaPartnerConversion%3A<conversion>)":{"campaign":"urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:<campaign>","conversion":"urn:lla:llaPartnerConversion:<conversion>"},"(campaign:urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredCampaign%3A<campaign2>,conversion:urn%3Alla%3AllaPartnerConversion%3A<conversion>)":{"campaign":"urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:<campaign2>","conversion":"urn:lla:llaPartnerConversion:<conversion>"}}}'
```